# Xcode Point System Iphone Trivia Game

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a beginner at creating iPhone apps and am trying to incorporate a simple point system for an iphone trivia game. Here is an basic overview of the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC0CI.png

So basically what I'm trying to do is make the user type the answer in the textfield. After typing an answer, they would click the button "Answer". If the answer is correct, an alert would show up saying "Correct", adding 100. If incorrect, it would say "Incorrect", subtracting 100.

However here is the problem: when you first answer correctly or incorrectly, the number remains at 0. When you click the button a second time, then it would properly increase/decrease. How do you fix this?

Here is my .h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
NSString *stringpoint;
int point;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textAnswer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *pointlabel;

-(IBAction) checkAnswer;

@end
```

.m file

```
    @synthesize textAnswer, pointlabel;
int point=0;

-(IBAction)checkAnswer {
pointlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",point];
if ([textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"fruit"]) {
point=point+100;
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Correct!" 
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
} else {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Incorrect"
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
point=point-100;
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
}
```

I am using Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the label that shows points before you calculate the new total, just need to move it to after:

```
-(IBAction)checkAnswer {
    // don't do this here, too early
    // pointlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",point];
    if ([textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"fruit"]) {
        point=point+100;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Correct!" 
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Incorrect"
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        point=point-100;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    // now you've changed value of points above, so update the label
    pointlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",point];
}
```

Comment: no problem, we've all been there! welcome to Stack Overflow. It's customary to accept the answer if correct, and upvote if you like, and I'd appreciate it ;) Objective-C is hard. If you've already given something your best shot, don't be shy about posting what you've tried and asking questions.